# Что означает код (python,pytorch)

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, pytorch

что означает код:

```
for in_channel, out_channel, stride, num_block in [
[       64,          64,     1,       2],
[       64,         128,     2,       2],
[      128,         256,     2,       2],
[      256,         512,     2,       2],
]:
self.encode.append(
    nn.Sequential(
       Basic( in_channel, out_channel,  stride=stride, ),
    *[ Basic(out_channel, out_channel,  stride=1,      ) for i in range(1, num_block) ]
    )
)
```

- Мне не очень понятно, почему"*" используется? Почему нет звездочки перед первым упоминанием класса Basic
- Зачем используется "for i in range(1, num_block)" ?
- Тут я вижу класс в классе (класс Basic внутри класса net) Означает ли это, что методы класса Basic не используются?
- Я думала, что "out_channel" должно быть равно "in_channel" в следующем слое. Если знак звездочка означает "И", то какое значение у "out_channel" во "втором" классе Basic

Полный код:

```
class Basic(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channel, out_channel, stride=1, is_shortcut=False):
        super(Basic, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d( in_channel, out_channel, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1   = BatchNorm2d(out_channel)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channel, out_channel, kernel_size=3, stride=1,      padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2   = BatchNorm2d(out_channel)

        self.is_shortcut =  in_channel != out_channel or stride!=1
        if self.is_shortcut:
            self.shortcut = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_channel, out_channel, kernel_size=1, padding=0, stride=stride, bias=False),
                BatchNorm2d(out_channel)
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.is_shortcut:
            shortcut = self.shortcut(x)
        else:
            shortcut = x

        x = self.bn1(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(x,inplace=True)
        x = self.bn2(self.conv2(x)) +  shortcut
        x = F.relu(x,inplace=True)
        return x

class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_channel=3, num_class=4):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.encode = nn.ModuleList([
            nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_channel, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False),
                BatchNorm2d(64),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                #nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3,stride=2,padding=1)
            )
        ])

        for in_channel, out_channel, stride, num_block in [
            [       64,          64,     1,       2],
            [       64,         128,     2,       2],
            [      128,         256,     2,       2],
            [      256,         512,     2,       2],
        ]:
            self.encode.append(
                nn.Sequential(
                   Basic( in_channel, out_channel,  stride=stride, ),
                *[ Basic(out_channel, out_channel,  stride=1,      ) for i in range(1, num_block) ]
                )
            )


        self.decode = nn.ModuleList([
            Decode( 512+256, 256),
            Decode( 256+128, 128),
            Decode( 128+ 64,  64),
            Decode(  64+ 64,  32),
            Decode(  32+  0,  16),
        ])

        self.logit = nn.Conv2d(16, num_class, kernel_size=1)



    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size,C,H,W = x.shape

        x = self.encode[0](x) ;  e0=x #; print('encode[0] :', x.shape)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, kernel_size=3,stride=2,padding=1)

        x = self.encode[1](x) ;  e1=x #; print('encode[1] :', x.shape)
        x = self.encode[2](x) ;  e2=x #; print('encode[2] :', x.shape)
        x = self.encode[3](x) ;  e3=x #; print('encode[3] :', x.shape)
        x = self.encode[4](x) ;  e4=x #; print('encode[4] :', x.shape)

        #exit(0)
        x = self.decode[0](x,e3)      #; print('decode[0] :', x.shape)
        x = self.decode[1](x,e2)      #; print('decode[1] :', x.shape)
        x = self.decode[2](x,e1)      #; print('decode[2] :', x.shape)
        x = self.decode[3](x,e0)      #; print('decode[3] :', x.shape)
        x = self.decode[4](x)         #; print('decode[3] :', x.shape)

        #x = F.dropout(x, 0.5, training=self.training)
        logit = self.logit(x)
        return logit


net = Net().cuda()
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(CHECKPOINT_FILE, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage))


net.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    logit = net(input)
    probability= torch.sigmoid(logit)

print('input: ',input.shape)
print('logit: ',logit.shape)
print('')
```

Answer (score 1):

этот код создает список параметров в виде `list`

```py
[ Basic(out_channel, out_channel,  stride=1,      ) for i in range(1, num_block) ]
```

это является единичным параметром

```py
Basic( in_channel, out_channel,  stride=stride, )
```

преобразует в последовательность единичных параметров
 `*[ Basic(out_channel, out_channel,  stride=1,      ) for i in range(1, num_block) ]`

тоесть Вы получаете на выходе обычный список параметров

```py
Basic( in_channel, out_channel,  stride=stride, ), Basic(out_channel, out_channel,  stride=1,      ), Basic(out_channel, out_channel,  stride=1,      ), Basic(out_channel, out_channel,  stride=1,      ), Basic(out_channel, out_channel,  stride=1,      )... и так далее
```

может быть этот пример поможет Вам понять что делает звездочка. попробуйте запустить:

```
print([a for a in range(10)], sep='\n')
print(*[a for a in range(10)], sep='\n')
print([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], sep='\n')
print(*[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], sep='\n')
print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Меня тут смущает тот факт, что Basic это класс, а не цифры. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что Вы имеете ввиду под единичным параметром? Я правильно понимаю, код означает, что к encode добавляются в конец: Basic( in_channel, out_channel,  stride=stride, ), Basic(out_channel, out_channel,  stride=1,      ), Basic(out_channel, out_channel,  stride=1,      )? Если количество Basic больше, то как мне понять сколько?

Comment: @Света, в вашем случае получается список экземпляров класса `Basic` которые, после того как звездочкой раскрыт список, используются как аргументы для `nn.Sequential`. В моем примере цифры это аргументы для `print`. под единичным параметром я имею ввиду один экземпляр класса, если бы небыло `*` то вторым единичным параметром стал бы список экземпляров класса `Basic` а со звездочкой получается последовательность экземпляров класса `Basic` каждый из которых является единичным параметром.

Comment: @Света, не в обиду. Вернитесь к азам python. Вы, видимо, очень много пропустили

Comment: @Света Как понять сколько: `num_block` значение этой переменной является количеством циклов генератора, соответственно равно количеству параметров (экземпляров класса `Basic`) которые этот генератор создаст, в вашем случае генератор создаст num_block - 1 параметр, поскольку начало диапазона задано со второго элемента

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Я правильно понимаю, в итоге к encode добавляются в конец: Basic( 64, 64, stride=1), Basic(64, 64, stride=1, ), Basic( 64, 128, stride=2), Basic(128, 128, stride=1, ), Basic( 128, 256, stride=2), Basic(256, 256, stride=1, ), Basic( 256, 512, stride=2), Basic(512, 512, stride=1, )